# Excel find specific number of characters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find in an excel list within cells all the consecutive 16 numbers without spaces
Is there a way to search for that ?

I want it to find all the numbers, 16 in total, but ignoring all the other text in the cell

Thank you

The numbers are not the same all the time, so i can't Ctrl F ... it's a string of 16 numbers

Comment: It is unfortunately not clear what exactly you mean, can you please add an example ...

Comment: As duDE said, your question is not clear.
I am assuming you mean you want to find some string in a cell where that is not the only string? For example, a cell contains "123456789" and you want to find "456", of this is the case then using a filter will work. However I do not understand the "the numbers are not the same .... so I can't Ctrl F" bit, surely you can just change the value you are searching for?

Comment: Is your question about taking the substring from a cell and the substring has to be exactly 16 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The following *User Defined Function* **UDF** will return the first instance of 16 consecutive digits in a string:

```
Public Function SweetSixteen(s As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, CH As String, j As Long
    L = Len(s)
    j = 0
    SweetSixteen = ""

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
            SweetSixteen = SweetSixteen & CH
            j = j + 1
            If j = 16 Then Exit Function
        Else
            j = 0
            SweetSixteen = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

If there is more than one valid substring, only the first will be returned.  If there is no valid substring, a Null will be returned.  If a substring has more than 16 digits, only the first 16 will be returned.
Here are some samples:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=SweetSixteen(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**